# How to plot two or more labels of one word in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, nlp

I came into problem in plotting the word with sentiments of 1 to 5 as

> 

```html
['dotcom', 13, 12, 17, 6, 13],
 ['graelam', 1, 2, 3, 2, 0],
 ['oprahin', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 ['jeffi', 2, 2, 3, 7, 0],
 ['assuar', 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
 ['ausio', 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
 ['sweeeeet', 2, 1, 0, 5, 7],
 ['atual', 3, 5, 8, 4, 4],
 ['estraing', 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 ['affilait', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 ['radioshark', 8, 4, 9, 4, 3],
 ['illuminati', 53, 45, 52, 37, 12],
 ['providedth', 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
 ['recategor', 5, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 ['redondo', 2, 2, 0, 6, 2],
 ['dybl', 1, 0, 1, 2, 0],
 ['gebhardt', 0, 1, 1, 2, 2],
 ['isanyway', 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
```

where in each list there is word and containing counts of words of labels [1,2,3,4,5] resp.
I want to plot those how they words are related with different labels. How can i do that?
Thanks for your idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my solution `x-axis` consists of each word labels, and `y-axis` consists of belonging classes. Code is shown below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pred = [['dotcom', 13, 12, 17, 6, 13], \
       ['graelam', 1, 2, 3, 2, 0],\
       ['oprahin', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],\
       ['jeffi', 2, 2, 3, 7, 0],\
       ['assuar', 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],\
       ['ausio', 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],\
       ['sweeeeet', 2, 1, 0, 5, 7],\
       ['atual', 3, 5, 8, 4, 4],\
       ['estraing', 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],\
       ['affilait', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],\
       ['radioshark', 8, 4, 9, 4, 3],\
       ['illuminati', 53, 45, 52, 37, 12],\
       ['providedth', 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],\
       ['recategor', 5, 0, 1, 0, 0],\
       ['redondo', 2, 2, 0, 6, 2],\
       ['dybl', 1, 0, 1, 2, 0],\
       ['gebhardt', 0, 1, 1, 2, 2],\
       ['isanyway', 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]]
pred = np.asarray(pred)
predicted_val = pred[:,1:].astype(int)
predicted_val = np.transpose(predicted_val)

prediction_results = pred

word_list = pred[:,0].astype(str)
word_list = word_list.tolist()
classes = ['Class-0', 'Class-1', 'Class-2', 'Class-3', 'Class-4']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(predicted_val)

# We want to show all ticks...
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(word_list)))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(len(classes)))
ax.set_xticklabels(word_list)
ax.set_yticklabels(classes)

# Rotate the tick labels and set their alignment.
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha="right",
         rotation_mode="anchor")

# Loop over data dimensions and create text annotations.
for i in range(len(classes)):
    for j in range(len(word_list)):
        text = ax.text(j, i, predicted_val[i, j],
                       ha="center", va="center", color="w")

#ax.set_title("")
fig.tight_layout()
cbar = ax.figure.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

Plotted figure:

[image]

Comment: @nerd You are welcome. I don't know which metrics are frequently used in nlp. ROC curve, confusion matrix, and heat map are frequently plotted in various tasks of ML. I get example code from https://matplotlib.org/